# get segfault when creating a pointer c++

Tags: c++

I got a `Segmentation fault` error when I compile it on an online c++ compiler. (The line that throws the error will be pointed out by a comment in the code)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class A
{

};

class B:public A
{

};


using namespace std;
class Base
{
public:
    int b;
    std::shared_ptr<A> Display()
    {
        cout<<"Base: Non-virtual display."<<endl;
    };
    virtual void vDisplay()
    {
        cout<<"Base: Virtual display."<<endl;
    };
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    int d;
    std::shared_ptr<B> Display()
    {
        cout<<"Derived: Non-virtual display."<<endl;
    };
    virtual void vDisplay()
    {
        cout<<"Derived: Virtual display."<<endl;
    };
};

int main()
{
    cout<<"Hello World"<<endl;
    Derived d;
    d.Display();

    Base *b = new Derived; // this line thorws the error
    b->vDisplay();
    return 0;
}
```

I got a bit confused; if I just create an object instead of pointer, then it's good. Where did I make a mistake?

Comment: Did you enable compiler warnings? If not, enable them with `-Wall` and read and fix them.

Comment: What @tkausl said. With a few flags you could catch and fix errors like this very quickly. For `g++` and `clang++` I suggest starting with: `-Wall -Wextra -Wshadow -Weffc++ -pedantic -pedantic-errors`. Tere are a lot more but these will catch a lot of simple mistakes.

Comment: Example fixes for the things caught by using the proper flags: https://godbolt.org/z/SBXDRR

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error actually happens on the previous line `d.Display();`. Control flow leaves `Derived::Display()` function without returning `std::shared_ptr<B>` causing Undefined Behavior.

As other people suggest, it would be a good idea to enable compiler warnings and / or actually pay attention to them. This is that one rare case when compilers tend to actually warn about potentially Undefined behavior in your program.

Comment: but why "Control flow leaves Derived::Display() function without returning std::shared_ptr<B>" ? why not throw an error in time?

Comment: Undefined behaviour is ... undefined.

Comment: @Henry Not sure what do you mean by "why not throw an error in time". It is just that language spec says that program behavior is undefined in this case.

Comment: @VTT I mean why not throw an error in the first place? so `undefined` means that even the compiler doesn't know what to do, so it just leaves it to a later time when something "defined" happens, like when it has to throw an error?

Comment: @Henry there is no error because your code is not valid c++, compilers cannot care about all possible invalid programs one could write. If you break the rules you can only hope for the best. Declaring to return something and then not return something is breaking the rule.

Comment: @VTT and why does it work when I simply create an object instead of creating a pointer?

Comment: @Henry because anything can happen when you have undefined behaviour, including: it seems to work (which is actually the worst case)

Comment: @Henry "throwing an error" would be a well-defined behavior. "Undefined Behavior" means that program compilation and execution outcomes are not predictable. For example on older VC++ lack of return statement was causing compiler crash due to codegen getting broken. If program has Undefined Behavior then it is typically a waste of time to reason why would program do one thing and not the other.

Comment: @Henry the return value is not `undefined` like in javascript. Your code invoke *undefined behaviour*. When this happens, *anything* can happen. It could work, print `meow` in the console, shutdown your computer or simply crash. If you enable warnings, the compiler will inform you of obvious errors.

Comment: @Henry if you really want to obtain meaningful diagnostic, use proper tooling like ubsan, valgrind or other analizers